# How to get content of file inside package

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.6

I am writing something in Python where I want to use predefined texts from files within the package. Somehow I can't manage to get it to work in Eclipse PyDev Console.

[image: filepath]

This is my path structure. From "story.py" I want to use the content of "starttext".

I tried open() with multiple variations of os.getcwd() and os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) which resulted in

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\starttext'

My last attempt was trying something like

```
import pkg_resources
resource_package = __name__
resource_path = '/'.join(('.', 'starttext'))
template = pkg_resources.resource_stream(resource_package, resource_path)
```

resulting in:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1232, in resource_stream
    self, resource_name
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1479, in get_resource_stream
    return io.BytesIO(self.get_resource_string(manager, resource_name))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1482, in get_resource_string
    return self._get(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36-64\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1560, in _get
    "Can't perform this operation for loaders without 'get_data()'"
NotImplementedError: Can't perform this operation for loaders without 'get_data()'
```

which appears to have something to do with python 3.x?

This seems to be such an easy task and I don't understand whats wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

**update**

Thanks to ShmulikA I changed it to:

```
    from os.path import dirname, join, abspath
    filename = join(dirname(abspath(communitybot.anthology.teststory.story.__file__)), 'starttext')
    file = open(filename, 'r')

    content = file.read()
```

This works although I think it is a little bit long, but I'm certain I am still doing something wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you are missing a `\` - use `os.path.join`:

```
from os.path import dirname, join, abspath
filename = join(dirname(abspath(__file__)), 'starttext')
file = open(filename, 'r')
```

- `__file__` - the path to the module's source file (you can also do import `requests;requests.__file__`)
- `os.path.abspath` - returns the absolute filename (e.g. `abspath('..')` returns `/home`)
- `os.path.dirname` - returns the dirname of a file
- `os.path.join` - joins a file parts compatible on both linux and windows

Comment: This feels pretty close but I get "NameError: name '__file__' is not defined".

Comment: do you run this in interpreter? `__file__` is defined when you executing a file not inside python interpreter/ ipython

Comment: I try to run it in Eclipse PyDev console.

Comment: its the same, `__file__` is referencing the current module that is being executed so you should probably use the base path of the project or use (instead of `__file__`):

`import story;story.__file__`

Comment: `import communitybot.anthology.teststory;communitybot.anthology.teststory.story.__file__`

`'D:\\Google Drive\\Development\\workspace\\eclipse\\storybot\\communitybot\\anthology\\teststory\\story.py'`

I think thats it. Thank you so much for your fast response!

Comment: sure u welcome. in any case you'd better off using a settings.py module and there define something like `ROOTDIR` to reference all files in the project